# (c++) How to make a function which can handle different type and number of parameters?

Tags: c++, function

For example, I'm working on an `gotoIJ` function, which set the pointer at the desired coordinate. I want 2 ways of passing argument into it:

- 2 `int` values: `gotoIJ(int i, int j)`
- a struct which store the coordinate: `gotoIJ(coordinate element)`

How to write it in C++? Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried - what's stopping you from creating two gotoJ methods each of which accept the arguments you require ?

Comment: Ever heard of *function overloading*? [Find a good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and read about it.

Answer (score 4):

Implement two functions:

```
struct Coordinate {
    int i;
    int j;
};

void gotoIJ(int i, int j) {
   // do stuff
}

void gotoIJ(const Coordinate& c) {
    gotoIJ(c.i, c.j);
}
```

Now clients can call:

```
gotoIJ(13, 42);
```

or:

```
Coordinate c1 {4, 2};
gotoIJ(c1);
```

---

See [Function overloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading) for details.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the function is not the only thing that distinguish the function itself from other functions. When you create (or better **declare**) a function you tell the compiler about 3 important and different points:

- return type
- function's name
- parameters passed to the function

in your case you want to use the same *function's name* but different *parameters* . You can do it without problems and create those two functions as you wrote in your question.

```
void gotoIJ(int i, int j){
...
}

void gotoIJ(coordinate element){
...
}
```

I guess you don't return anything from those functions and therefore I set the returning type to *void* .
So when in your main or anywhere else you call the function **gotoIJ**, the compiler will automatically call the correct one according to the parameters you pass.